# Add several lines of variable text in fixed positions to a ggplot facet

Tags: r, date, text, ggplot2, facet

I am tryig to add several lines of text to this facet. Sorry about the mess of code

[image]

From the object `means1` I want to add the values of the variables "pCensCom" "pCensEx" and "pCensReg" for each facet, as described in the following figure

[image]

This is the object 'censTot1' used to build the chart

```
        censo     censTot           tipoAni     censAn       año     pCensAn
1: 2010-01-01          42     Hembra adulta         27      2010   64.285714
2: 2010-01-01          42             Joven          4      2010    9.523810
3: 2010-01-01          42      Macho adulto          1      2010    2.380952
4: 2010-01-01          42           Ternero         10      2010   23.809524
5: 2010-01-02          42     Hembra adulta         27      2010   64.285714

---                                                       
7300: 2014-12-30       57            Ternero         16      2014   28.070175
7301: 2014-12-31       57      Hembra adulta         32      2014   56.140351
7302: 2014-12-31       57              Joven          7      2014   12.280702
7303: 2014-12-31       57       Macho adulto          2      2014    3.508772
7304: 2014-12-31       57            Ternero         16      2014   28.070175
```

The following describes the code used to design the figure

```
# Plot color background 
# %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

bg0<-data.table()
for(i in 1:5){
bg<-data.table(xstart=c(as.Date(paste0(años[i],"-01-01"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date(paste0(años[i],"-03-21"), format="%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date(paste0(años[i],"-06-21"),format = "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date(paste0(años[i],"-09-21"),format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                      as.Date(paste0(años[i],"-12-21"),format = "%Y-%m-%d")),xend=c(as.Date(paste0(años[i],"-03-21"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                      as.Date(paste0(años[i],"-06-21"),format = "%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date(paste0(años[i],"-09-21"),format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                      as.Date(paste0(años[i],"-12-21"),format = "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date(paste0(años[i],"-12-31"),format = "%Y-%m-%d")),
             Estacion=c("Invierno","Primavera","Verano","Otoño","Invierno"))
l=list(bg0,bg); bg0<-rbindlist(l, fill=TRUE)
}

bg0<-bg0[,Estacion:=factor(ordered(Estacion,levels=c("Invierno","Primavera", "Verano", "Otoño")))]
cbPalette<-c("#FF3300","#006633","#FFFF00","#0000FF")
plotbg<-ggplot()+ geom_rect(data = bg0, aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, fill = Estacion), alpha = 0.10)+ scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)+ guides(fill=FALSE)+theme_bw()


means1<-data.table(tipoAni=c("Hembra adulta","Joven","Macho adulto","Ternero"),pCensCom=c(62.3,17.8,0.9,19.37),pCensEx=c(61.4,16.1,1.9,20.6),pCensReg=c(63.0,17.9,1.6,24.7))


# Plot
# %%%%
plotbg + geom_line(data=censTot1,aes(x=censo,y=pCensAn))+ facet_grid(tipoAni ~ .)+ xlab("Censos diarios") + ylab("Animales (%)") +theme_bw()+ theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=8),strip.text.y = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),strip.background = element_rect(colour="red", fill="#CCCCFF"))
```

Please I need help, I tried several times using the functions `annotation_custom`, `grobTree` and `textGrob` and I have not been able to achieve

Comment: Could you not make a simpler example that shows the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified answer. First I simulate some data `dat`, then a second data.table `backgr` that has the information for the background, and lastly `textdt`, which holds the information about the text elements.

The code looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

dat <- data.table(x = rep(1:100, 2),
                  group = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 100),
                  val = rnorm(200))

dat[, price := 100 + cumsum(val), by = group]

# plot empty

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = price)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(group~.)

# plot with added polygons
# for the background colors
backgr <- data.table(minval = c(10, 40, 60, 90), 
                     maxval = c(20, 60, 80, 100),
                     backgroup = LETTERS[1:4])
# for the text elements
textdt <- data.table(xval = c(10, 50, 70),
                     yval = c(105, 100, 95),
                     textlabel = c("foo", "bar", "lorum"),
                     group = c("A", "A", "B"))

# plot
ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data = backgr, aes(xmin = minval, xmax = maxval, ymin = -Inf, 
                               ymax = Inf, fill = backgroup)) +
  geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = price)) + 
  geom_text(data = textdt, aes(x = xval, y = yval, label = textlabel, 
                               group = group)) + 
  facet_grid(group~.) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"), 0.5))
```

Which results in a plot like this, which you can adjust to fit your data:
[image: Plot]

Comment: Thanks for your help David, I like your solution, but my problem is that I work with dynamic reports, and the Y-axis scale varies widely, therefore need to add text in a fixed location regardless of plot scale. I think the solution is to use the function 'annotation_custom' adding text in a fixed location regardless of plot scales, but so far not work for me.

Comment: Or you determine the `ymin` value as `min(val) + (max(val) - min(val))*0.9`, which sets the label at 90% of the plots height

Comment: Does it work for you? If so, please consider marking it as the answer!